# Best way to change between views in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, navigation, uiwindow

How do you go from one view to another? Is

```
[window addSubview:myView];
```

The only option or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First look at Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).  You might start with a navigation-based interface it sounds. What you say is strictly true, but you want to take advantage of features like animation, which come for 'free' if you use Apple's view controller classes.

Comment: I did try out UINavigationController but when I initialize and push myView2 from myView1 using pushViewController:animated it doesn't work. I get the SIGABRT signal when I click the button which is supposed to take me to myView2(on click of that button, I have used the above method) Please advise.

Comment: Resources like this: http://www.matthewcasey.co.uk/2010/05/23/tutorial-introducing-uinavigationcontroller-part-1/ are a good start; you will need Part 2 of this tutorial to complete a navigation-based sample app.   A good read of navigation controllers is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1

Comment: @petert I am also looking for the "Best way to change between views in iOS" 99% people said what you said use UINavigationController, but what if after login the controller I want to push is uitabbarcontroller? UITabBarController cannot be pushed in UINavigationController.